# Regex find match word with some range front word

Tags: regex

I Have a list of Word

- "Dany buy some pear and apple"
- "Dany eat the apple"
- "Dany love apple"
- "Dany make apple pie"

I really dont understand the keyword what is this.
But i want make some like this 
Dany{2}(apple) =  find dany with the apple but max between dany and apple is 2 word

so it will give the result

```
Dany love apple
Dany make apple pie
Dany eat the apple
```

Comment: Not sure, but try: `Dany\s([\S]+\s){1,2}apple`

Comment: I like that @RiteshKhandekar. Maybe some word boundaries to prevent apple and Dany from being substring. Also you can remove the `[` and `]` around `\S` I guess.

Comment: I try your solution and is work well, and when change the word and the length is still give result the same thing :)

https://regex101.com/r/y8JLtI/1 
Thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may look for it:

```
Dany\s+(\w+\s+){0,2}apple.*
```

[Example](https://regex101.com/r/eSTDvE/2/)

Answer (score 1):

This might do the trick `.*Dany (?=(?:\w*(?: \w*)?)? apple).*`.https://regex101.com/r/8ouNpf/5.

Comment: That solved the current problem, but how i can add more between length like

Comment: change `(?: \w*)?` this part with length-1. So if you want let say max 5 word, then `(?: \w*){0,4}`